gtts now playing audio in a for loop
Here is my code on Google Colab
!pip install gTTS
from gtts import gTTS
from IPython.display import Audio
import os
## Some irrelevant code that generates the list of "items" that contain strings
for i in items:
  print(i)
  tts = gTTS(i)
  tts.save('1.wav')
  sound_file = '1.wav'
  Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True)

This will print the items properly but does not play any sound. However, if I run the last four lines out of the loop, it plays the audio fine for the last item in the list.
tts = gTTS(i)
tts.save('1.wav')
sound_file = '1.wav'
Audio(sound_file, autoplay=True)

Where did I do wrong? I have tried adding time.sleep(5) at the end of the loop and it doesn't help.
Thanks!
